# Get Previous Line while reading Log File in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a log file which I am reading and getting what I need. But I have an additional trouble.

I want to get the line which is before the line which has keyword "Error"

I tried to use

```
Get-Content -Path $File -Tail 2  | Select-String -Pattern $Patterns -Context 1,0 -SimpleMatch
```

This is also giving me an output which I need. But after doing that I want to extract data from the two lines. Can I use a foreach loop on the output?

```
$Patterns  = @('execution ended')

$File= "C:\GProcess\log.txt"
#-Context 1,0
Get-Content -Path $File -Tail 2  | Select-String -Pattern $Patterns -Context 1,0 -SimpleMatch
```

Current Output is

```
  Process failed as there was an error
> Process execution ended
```

Maybe I just want `Process failed as there was an error` but search for keyword "execution ended"

I hope I have explained my query properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get just the line(s) of the context directly.

```
$match = Get-Content -Path $File  | Select-String -Pattern $Patterns -Context 1,0 -SimpleMatch
$match.Context.PreContext
```

Comment: Nice one +1, aliased and shorted `(gc $File -Tail 2|sls $Patterns -Con 1,0 -Sim).Context.Precontext`

Comment: But How do I loop into this? When used the above code, It is not printing any data..

Comment: I tried this way.. But does not work..
    `$match = Get-Content -Path $File.FullName | Select-String -Pattern 
    $searchpattern -Context 1,0 -SimpleMatch 
    $match.Context.PreContext | foreach {
    $time,$type, $jsondata = $PSItem -split " ",3
    $data = ConvertFrom-Json $jsondata
    $data.message
    }`

Comment: Found the issue.. It was not -tail.. It was -SimpleMatch which was causing issue

Answer (score 0):

The below code will give you the line number of your string search, rather than using -tail.

If you have that then you can code the extra bit you need to grab the line above or below quite easily.

```
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\GProcess\log.txt' | Select-String -Pattern 'error').LineNumber
```