# Select-String after line break

Tags: powershell, select-string

I want to extract the ID from this command:

```
    manage-bde -protectors c: -get
```

The result of this command is:

```
Volume C: [Windows]
Tous les protecteurs de clés

    Mot de passe numérique :
      ID : {XXXXXXX-A315-42C6-9754-XXXXXXXXXX}
      Mot de passe :
        XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX

    TPM :
      ID : {XXXXXX-99B3-481B-B3FA-XXXXXXXXXXX}
      Profil de validation PCR :
        7, 11
        (Utilise le démarrage sécurisé pour la validation d’intégrité.)
```

I want only the ID from the "Mot de passe numérique" (first one, but on some PC, it's the second one) and not the "TPM"

I tried to do that with select-string, but it return both :/

Is there a way to "tell" to select-string to print only the ID after the "mot de passe numérique" expression ?

Thx :)

Comment: `Select-String` has a `-Context` parameter. Take a look here:  [Get Previous Line while reading Log File in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54362796/10223991)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Previous Line while reading Log File in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362073/get-previous-line-while-reading-log-file-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Select-String`'s `-Context` parameter to indicate that you're interested in the lines *surrounding* a match:

```
$mbdeOutput = manage-bde -protectors c: -get

$mbdeOutput |Select-String 'Mot de passe numérique :' -Context 0,1 |ForEach-Object { $_.Context.PostContext[0] }
```

This should output the line immediately following `Mot de passe numérique :`

Comment: Thx ! it works, i had to put "rique : " instead "Mot de passe numérique :", select-string does not like "é" character :)